# Tree Component Item Rendering

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have created a MyTreeItemrenderer extending TreeItemrenderer.

However, I do not want any label, folder, disclosure icon nor icon.
I want to dispaly every node of the tree with my own graphic like eg: a line, round image etc.,

Kindly help me getting the solution.

Thnaks in advance...

Narender R

Answer (score 0):

I think the styles you're looking for are. In this case I'm setting them to null, but you should be able to add a graphic with them.

defaultLeafIcon="{null}"

folderClosedIcon="{null}"

folderOpenIcon="{null}"